# How to put Bootstrap 3 Wells on the same row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my Bootstrap 3 [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71j5psr0/35/), although you'll likely need to view it in full screen view in order to see it in all its glory.

As you can see, there are two TB3 "wells" called **Herps** and **Derps**. They are currently sitting on top of one another, and furthermore, they are wider than the navbar, jumbotron and footer wells.

I'd like these to both be next to each other on the same line/"row", and I'd like the two wells to be the same width of all the other contents. I'd also like to have a bit of padding (spacing) between the two wells so that they're not smushed right up next to each other.

My best attempt (from that jsFiddle above):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well">Herps</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well">Derps</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...does not seem to be doing the trick. Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `col-x-y` css styles for your wells for the appropriate screen size and columns. In this case, you could use `col-sm-6` since you have two columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well">Herps</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well">Derps</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71j5psr0/36/)

[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)